# Sitecore 9.1 Installation SitecoreInstallFramework

Tags: asp.net, powershell, installation, sitecore, sitecore9

I am trying to install Sitecore 9.1 on my PC for development. I followed [this](https://tothecore.sk/2018/11/28/sitecore-9-1-initial-release-installation-guide-for-development-machine/) short tutorial and also referenced it against the Sitecore 9.1 *Quick Installation Guide*. *Slor* seems to have installed without issue. The following error occurs when executing the **XP0-SingleDeveloper.ps1** script which is one of the last steps of the tutorial. This is the first ever Sitecore instance ever installed on this machine.

[image: Powershell Error]

The error seems to be occurring within the *SitecoreInstallFramework\2.0.0\Private\JsonConfiguration.ps1* file. I used the `Install-Module SitecoreInstallFramework – Force` & `Update-Module SitecoreInstallFramework` powershell commands multiple times to ensure my SitecoreInstallFramework is up to date. Any ideas on how to resolve this? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried running the prerequisites for 9.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Error is about the Identity Server Package, Check you have the package on disk in $SCInstallRoot.
For 9.1 on premise:

> Sitecore.IdentityServer 2.0.0 rev. * (OnPrem)_identityserver.scwdp.zip

You need to unzip the Sitecore download to found the WDP and JSON files,

In your PowerShell script check this lines:

```
# The path to the Identity Server Package to Deploy.
$IdentityServerPackage = (Get-ChildItem "$SCInstallRoot\Sitecore.IdentityServer 2.0.0 rev. * (OnPrem)_identityserver.scwdp.zip").FullName
```

Make sure you set the root folder for the WDP files, something like C:\ResourceFiles or this:

```
# The root folder with the license file and WDP files.
$SCInstallRoot = "C:\Sitecore\910"
```

Check your WDP files are not blocked after download, To "unblock" a file, right-click it in Windows Explorer, choose Properties from the context menu, click the Unblock button in the lower right-hand corner of the resulting dialog, and hit OK or Apply